# Function update string or value if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to write a `function` which returns the `value` from `input:radio` or `text()` from `span`, when `checkbox` is checked.

It is not necessary to return both. Either one or the other would be helpful.

This is `html` template example:

```js
$('input.choose-age').on('change', function() {
  $('input.choose-age').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" id='wom-10-14 age' class='choose-age' value='10-14' checked /> <span class='text-left'>10-14</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" id='wom-15-19 age' class='choose-age' value='15-19' /> <span class='text-left'>15-19</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" id='wom-10-19 age' class='choose-age' value='10-19' /> <span class='text-left'>10-19</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

**Attempt 1**

```
function ageLabel() {
    var label = $('input:radio').change(function() {
        var result = $('input:radio:checked').map(function() {
            var age = $(this).next('span').text();
            return age;
        }).get();
        return result[0];
    });
    return label;
};
```

**Attempt 2**

```
function ageLabel() {
    $('#age').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var result = $(this).next('span').text();
        };
        return result;
    });
};
```

**Attempt 3**

```
function ageLabel() {
    $('input:radio').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var results = $('input:radio:checked').map(function() {
                var aged = $(this).next('span').text();
                return aged;
            }).get();
            return results[0];
        };
    });
};
```

**Attempt 4**

```
function ageLabel() {
    d3.selectAll('#age').on('change', function() {
        val = this.value;
        return val;
    });
};
```

Each code above doesn't return the new `value` or `text()` when different `input` is checked.

How can I achieve this result?

Cheers!

Comment: No. Dont do this. If an asynchronous event(the label check) is dealt with an synchronous code, the browser thread is blocked until the event happened. This is not a good style. Use callbacks or promises...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest `d3` way is:

```js
d3.selectAll(".choose-age")
  .on("change", function(){
    console.log(this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox">
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-10-14 age' class='choose-age' value='10-14' checked /> <span class='text-left'>10-14</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-15-19 age' class='choose-age' value='15-19' /> <span class='text-left'>15-19</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-10-19 age' class='choose-age' value='10-19' /> <span class='text-left'>10-19</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDITS**

Completely missed the point of this question that you wanted to return the value in a function.  @jonasw's answer works but it's overly complicated. Couple simpler approaches.  First, you could jsut use a variable in the outer scope.

```
var ageLabel = '10-14';
d3.selectAll(".choose-age")
  .on("change", function(d){
    ageLabel = this.value;
  });
```

`ageLabel` will always have the value.

Or second, if you want a function, just select for the value:

```js
function ageLabel(){
  return d3.select(".choose-age:checked").node().value;
}

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(ageLabel());
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox">
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-10-14 age' class='choose-age' value='10-14' checked /> <span class='text-left'>10-14</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-15-19 age' class='choose-age' value='15-19' /> <span class='text-left'>15-19</span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-2'>
    <input type="radio" name="choose-age" id='wom-10-19 age' class='choose-age' value='10-19' /> <span class='text-left'>10-19</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Mark. I'll try to use your example according to the other answer.

Comment: @estebanpdl, see updated answer, I didn't understand what you were asking.  Jonas w's answer works, but is way over-complicated for you what you really want to do.

Comment: Great! Is a simple way to do it. I think I need something like this. But, when I `console.log(ageLabel())` and change to (i.e. 15-19) it still shows 10-14. Should I need to change something else? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @estebanpdl, `when I console.log(ageLabel()) and change it...` did you log, then change radio input?  It logs the current value at the time you call the function...

Comment: Exactly. I log, and then change radio input, hoping log update value at the time :S

Comment: @estebanpdl, `console.log` just doesn't work like that.  It just prints to the console when it's called.

Comment: Good answer as always, upvoted, but I believe you don't need the argument (`d` in `function(d)`) if you're just dealing with `this`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, you are correct of course.  It's a force of habit when using `d3` always passing the "magic" `d` around!

Comment: I wouldnt call my answer "overcomplicated" your answer is synchronous and a change is not detected, while my answer is asynchronous, wich is good for keeping the browsers thread free and reacting fast. Depends on what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Why your code doesnt work:

Atempt 1&3&4:
Label is a jquery element, your "return result[0]" will return the result somewhere into the jquery routine.

Atempt2:
the code returns result *now* while result is set somewhere in the future. So *now* it is undefined

How to do it:
Synchronously(not recommended):

```
function ageLabel(){
  while(true){
   if(labelischecked){
     break;
   }
   }
   return result;
  }
```

However this will block the browsers thread causing lagging and eventually crashing (bad!)

Asynchronously:
1.Callback:

```
function ageLabel(callback){
d3.selectAll(".choose-age") .on("change", function(d){callback(this.value);});
}

ageLabel((result)=>{
  //age label checked, so now work with result
 });

 // thanks to mark
```

2.Promise:

```
function ageLabel(){
 Return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
d3.selectAll(".choose-age") .on("change", function(d){resolve(this.value); });
});
}


ageLabel().then((result)=>{
//do sth with result
});
```

Comment: Thank for the advice, @Jonas. The result inside `ageLabel((result)=>{ });` using `Callback` is from example **Attempt 2**?

Comment: If you want it like in example **atempt 2**, resolve the callback like this 'callback($(this).next('span').text())'

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jonas. I will practice those examples.